# PHP Curl does not return JSON on ubuntu while it does on Windows

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, ubuntu-14.04

I have an URL that returns a JSON.

```
$url = "http://115.249.245.30:9001/speeddial/api/d2h.php"
$queryString = "?ANI=9810652710&RTN1=Uttar+Pradesh&RTN2=Bill+Related&PL=234&CustID=ASDIOASD&EmailID=&CustName=XXXX&AgentName1=Naveen&ComplaintId=101&Category=SMS&DateTime=10Apr%202015&CallTime=2016-04-30+14%3A45%3A00"
```

the Curl call on window works however on ubuntu system this does not return anything

here is the method snippet where this URL call is made

```
static function httpCurlCall($url, $querystring)
{
    $urlfinal = $url.$querystring;
    $ch = curl_init($urlfinal);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch)){ // this is to debug
       echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); // this is to debug
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Also, directly calling the URL return the correct result.

```
Error response on debug : Curl error: Failed to connect to 115.249.245.30 port 9001: Connection timed out
```

Where am I wrong.

Comment: May be firewall restriction issue.

Comment: Since this looks like a dialup IP range, might be a NAT issue. Did you perhaps try to connect to your own computer, and forgot to mention that?

Comment: Here you can check your network connection : http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=ping&host=115.249.245.30

Comment: can you `ping` 115.249.245.30 ?

Comment: @mario just looked into NAT, could be this. I will have to check.